# How to calculate area in SQL using geographic coordinates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

Does anybody know what is the problem with my query. I am trying to calculate area using geographical coordinates, but result seems to be too small to be true. 0.00118 sqm. Can anybody help?

```
SELECT ST_Area(the_geom) As sqm
FROM (SELECT
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON
(
  (14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125,
    14.595212295624522 121.08512878417969,
    14.567302046916149 121.124267578125,
    14.596541266841905 121.14761352539062,
    14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125)
)',4326) ) As foo(the_geom)
```

Comment: This looks like it has some info in the GIS stack exchange here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26461/calculating-area-of-an-epsg4326-polygon

Comment: Also check out this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139292/why-does-st-area-return-different-results-for-geog-vs-geom

Comment: As answered below, you need the `geography` version of ST_Area; [see the manual](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How accurate should be the calculation? 
A solution is to cast GEOMETRY to [GEOGRAPHY](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_Geography), which is acceptably accurate for the most use cases:

```
SELECT ST_Area(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY ) As sqm
FROM (SELECT
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON
(
  (14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125,
    14.595212295624522 121.08512878417969,
    14.567302046916149 121.124267578125,
    14.596541266841905 121.14761352539062,
    14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125)
)',4326) ) As foo(the_geom)
```

The geography type automatically converts degrees to meters.

Depending on your scenario you could also use directly the geography constructor [St_GeographyFromText](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeographyFromText.html), which accept a WKT string as argument, very similar to ST_GeomFromText

```
ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125,
        14.595212295624522 121.08512878417969,
        14.567302046916149 121.124267578125,
        14.596541266841905 121.14761352539062,
        14.604514925547997 121.0968017578125))'
    )
```